# PhpStorm- differences: "Terminal" and "Run Command"

Tags: ide, phpstorm, php-ide

I use PhpStorm. What is the differences between "Terminal"(Alt+F12) and "Run Command" (tools- run command).

Comment: This question is quite sometime ago. Did you find any answer for it? Since I have basically the same question. It confuses me a lot :S